# Is there a finale replacement for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

What is the best alternative to Finale (capable of opening and editing .mus files) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/finale/?platform=linux

Answer (score 7):

Try [MuseScore](http://musescore.org/).

> MuseScore is an open source cross platform music notation program that
>   has a lot of very good features. Simple to operate, notes are entered
>   on a virtual note sheet with your mouse, MIDI or keyboard.
>
> It also features a note editing input that is much like step-time note
>   entry that found on premium commercial music editing software.<sup>[MuseScore](http://musescore.org/)</sup>

To download, and other info click [Here](http://musescore.org/en/download).

Comment: The best replacement I found so far.